# Why does yum history look different?

Tags: yum

Earlier today when I typed `sudo yum history` I would get a list of operations with a heading like so:

```
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when I type it I get a slightly different heading:

```
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice that I used to have a column 'Login user' but now that column is replaced by 'Command line'

**Why did it change, and is there a way to switch between the two different outputs, or better yet show both columns together?**

yum 3.4.3 on CentOS 3.10.0-229 (x86_64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you had a yum update bringing the "Command line" column. From `man 5 yum.conf`:

> Older versions of yum acted like "users", which always outputs the user who initiated the yum transaction.

According with `man 5 yum.conf`, exists an option modifying yum output behavior. If you add `history_list_view=cmds` to `/etc/yum.conf` it shows "**Command line**", if you add `history_list_view=users` it shows "**Login user**".

If you want real details: [check the repo site](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/output.py), line 2054

Answer (score 2):

I found the column width of the commands to be ridiculously small (the package names are truncated and the package name includes the revision numbers and that is what I need to see), and I could not find an option to yum that would make it larger. It seems it is hard coded to yum and you need to edit the python to change it.

My work around is to grep `/var/log/messages` for `yum`.  In this case, you can see the full package name.

Comment: The truncated commands are indeed really annoying. I know we can have details with the `info` keyword, but not with a `yum --setopt=history_list_view=commands history list all` :(